# Which ASCII characters are forbidden for use in SGML attributes?

Tags: sgml

Apart from whitespace, quotation mark, equal sign, and tab, which other characters of the printable subset of ASCII are forbidden to be used as attribute names in SGML?

Comment: Isn't "tab" just a special case of "whitespace"?

Comment: I meant 0x20 whitespace, not logical whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, SGML allows only alphanumeric values for SGML names. What additional characters are allowed for SGML names is controlled by the SGML declaration; specifically `UCNMCHAR` and `LCNMCHAR` under `NAMING`.

For example, if you look at the [SGML declaration for HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/sgmldecl.html), you'll see:

```
LCNMCHAR ".-_:"    
UCNMCHAR ".-_:"
```

This means that the characters `.`, `-`, `_`, and `:` are also allowed in SGML names (element/attribute/entity/etc).

**NOTE: Only a letter is allowed as the first character of an SGML name.**

Comment: The reference concrete syntax has LCNMCHAR and UCNMCHAR ".-" instead of ".-_:".